# How to call describe or it function in afterEach function in jasmine

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I'd like to check button disable state after each `it` funtion. So I use `afterEach` function but error like below was occured.
How to call `describe` or `it` function in afterEach function or any workarround.

```
'it' should only be used in 'describe' function
```

```js
  describe('Input Error Check', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);

    afterEach( () => {
      const searchButon = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#searchButton')).nativeElement as HTMLButtonElement
      expect(searchButon.disabled).toBeTruthy()
    })

    it('No Input Value', () =>{
      // write test code
    })


    it('Invalid Input Value', () =>{
      // write test code
    })
    
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `afterEach` method is done for teardown logic only. [The jasmine docs about it say](https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.6/global.html#afterEach):

> Run some shared teardown after each of the specs in the describe in
> which it is called.

You might add this expect in the end of each test of make a small proxy like in the code below:

```
function withSearchButtonDisabled(testCallback) {
   return () => {
      testCallback();
      const searchButon = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#searchButton')).nativeElement as HTMLButtonElement
      expect(searchButon.disabled).toBeTruthy()
   }
}

  describe('Input Error Check', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);

    it('No Input Value', withSearchButtonDisabled(() =>{
      // write test code
    }))


    it('Invalid Input Value', withSearchButtonDisabled(() =>{
      // write test code
    }))
    
  })
```

PS I didn't test the code, there might be typos